# Pine script doesn't alert on first iteration

Tags: pine-script

This Pine Script does not seem to alert, am I doing something wrong or do I not understand how alerts in Pine Script works?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test alert on first iteration")

varip _alerted = false

if not _alerted
  and barstate.islast
    _alerted := true
    alert("testing", alert.freq_all)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script will be executed on every bar starting from the very first bar.

Therefore, `_alerted` will be `true` on the very first bar. Since you don't reset this flag, when you add this script to your chart, you won't get any alerts because `_alerted` will already be `true` at that point.

Comment: I've edited the script to only act on the last bar and onwards, but it still doesn't alert.